# rm -rf is not deleting .app file

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to delete `AdBlock Master.app` in my applications.I tried manually delete the file using drag-drop to trash, but it's
 not working.Then I went to terminal and did `rm -rf AdBlock Master.app` but the file is still there.Any suggestions?

Comment: That filename has a space - you are putting it in quotes or escaping the space aren't you?

Comment: I see now, thanks!

Comment: @John3136 how do you escape space in mac?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/266800/how-to-remove-file-which-has-white-space-in-name-from-unix